# Why is SonarQube's skippedModules property deprecated?

Tags: sonarqube

I am doing a Sonar analysis with Maven on a Maven multimodule project. I have to use sonar.skippedModules property frequently and ever since I have upgrade to SonarQube 4.3, I've noticed that this property is deprecated although I can still use it. Is there a reason for this property to be deprecated and will be be removed in future versions of SonarQube? I surely hope not.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, This has been been removed from SonarQube 4.3. You need to change the syntax. I am not sure what is the new syntax. But refer this :- https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARVS-31
And please like the post if you found this stuff useful.

Comment: That is interesting because excluding modules from the GUI page is effective. They mentioned wildcards feature, I really hope that gets added in.